# How to use vue-router params

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new to Vue now working with its router.

I want to navigate to another page and I use the following code:

```
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation', params: { foo: "bar"}});
```

Then I expect it to be on the new Component

```
this.$route.params
```

This doesn't work.
I also tried:

```
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation'});
this.$router.push({params: { foo: "bar"}});
```

I've inspected the source code a bit and noticed this property gets overwritten with a new object `{}`.

I'm wondering is the params use is other than I think?
If not, how to use it?

Comment: instead of pushing to path, push to name, then it will work.

Answer (score 56):

Since you want to pass params to the component of the respective route you route object's path property should have a dynamic segment denoted by `:` followed by the name of the key in your params object

so your routes should be

```js
routes: [
    {path: '/newLocation/:foo', name: 'newLocation', component: newComponent}
]
```

Then for programmatically navigating to the component  you should do:

```js
this.$router.push({name: 'newLocation', params: { foo: "bar"}});
```

See that I am using `name` of the route instead of `path` as you are passing params by the property `params`.

if you want to use `path` then it should be:

```js
this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation/bar'});
```

by the path approach the params will automatically map to corresponding fields on `$route.params`.

Now if you `console.log(this.$route.params)` in your new component you will get the object : `{"foo": "bar"}`

Comment: I don't know is Vue router worked differently in 2017, but now Vue router requires `props: true` on the route to even start parsing the `:foo` parts of the url

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I missed this.$router.params. I was assuming that when the param is passed, I can catch that param automatically when it's declared under data

Comment: I am using name but still getting params as empty on target page .

Answer (score 22):

Try using query instead of params

```
this.$router.push({path: '/newpath', query : { foo: "bar"}});
```

And in your component

```
console.log(this.$route.query.foo)
```

Comment: Works but it makes a weird URL. Since I'm passing an object it shows `http://...?player=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`. Any way to not have it do that?

Comment: @tazboy Did you find the way to solve it ? I also use an object as a prop for my route and in the URL, if my object has a 'name' field, I'd like to display it in the URL instead of the `%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Comment: I used localStorage to store what I needed instead of passing it using query. Much easier to use.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I've found is to use named routes along with the params options. Let's say you have a router file that looks like this:

[image: Vue Router File]

And you want to reach the "movie" page with some ID. You can use Vue's router link component (or Nuxt's link component) to reach it like this:

Vue:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'movie', params: { id: item.id } }">{{ item.title }}</router-link>
```

Nuxt:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'movie-id', params: { id: item.id } }">{{ item.title }}</nuxt-link>
```

**Note that the name parameter must match the "name" attribute of the desired route in the router file. And likewise, the parameter name must match.**

> Nuxt creates the route file for you automatically when you create a
> new page. To see what name Nuxt gives its routes, go to the .Nuxt
> folder in your project and look for a "router.js" file

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it generally considered an anti pattern to bind the properties to the router?

It's a much more DRY solution to have them bind to the component it's self, which I actually believe the Vue router does. Please see: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html for more info on the best practices here

Can you try accepting the property in the props: [] property of your component? You can see how to do that here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Please do pop up if you have any questions! Happy to help further.

Comment: I want to pass params form one view to another. sounds ok to me. when giving the route a name and then executing 'this.$router.push({path: '/newLocation', name: 'newRouteName', params: { foo: "bar"}});' did the trick and now i can access the params on my new loaded view via: this.$route.params. thanks for you time and effort!

Comment: one more thing, I can't see a reason why it must be named for it to work. do you have an idea?