# Nuxt.js: How do I create dynamic nuxt-links/routes per article?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble with figuring out dynamic nuxt-link.

On the main pages (`localhost:3030/`), there are articles that are fetched from the backend server by axios.

Each articles have to point to the route `localhost:3030/articles/:postid`.

The `:postid` value is stored in `axios.get` data, so that I can deal with them dynamically.

But, I'm not sure how to create dynamic `nuxt-link` where each article has its own `nuxt-link` pointing to its article contents (`/articles/:postid`)?

I tried to use `method` to execute `this.$router.push({ path: 'articles/:postid'})`, the route it points looks like this: `articles/:postid`

What would be the correct approach to route dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use vue-router params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296505/how-to-use-vue-router-params)

Comment: Yea it does! Since Nuxt.js creates routes based on the folder structure, I figured that `{ name: 'articles-id', params: { id: this.postid } }` solves the above. However, I'd like to know if same thing can be done using `nuxt-link` instead of methods.

Comment: You could bind the `to` attribute with dynamic data : `<nuxt-link :to="'/articles/' + postId">`

Comment: You are correct. It didn't work previously because I forgot to put `:` in front of to... Then, how should I use that `postid` from the child page??

Comment: You can access it with `this.$route.params.postid` or `$route.params.postid` from 
 the template. You can read more here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
  <nuxt-link :to="linkTo">Link</nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      linkTo: '/about'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

try this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First, you will have to create the proper folder structure which enables dymanic routing [file system routing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#dynamic-routes)

In your case, it could be

- pages/

  - articles/

    - _id.vue

Add a method to the parent page

`this.$router.push({ path:` /articles/${articleId} `});`

Which you will invoked when an article link is clicked. It will navigate to the _id.vue page which is the article page itself. On that page you can check the parameter id with `this.$route.params.id` if you want to pass is to fetch more data.