# Vue Router warning message "passed with params but they will be ignored"

Tags: vue.js

I'm running the following sample application on branch "added-vuex-to-ssr"

https://github.com/se22as/vue-3-with-router-basic-sample

When I run the sample application with SSR, I get the following Vue Router Warnings when I go to the home or about page. Can't find documentation for the warnings. Any help would be appreciated.

[Vue Router warn]: Path "/" was passed with params but they will be ignored. Use a named route alongside params instead.
[Vue Router warn]: Path "/about" was passed with params but they will be ignored. Use a named route alongside params instead.

Answer (score 8):

The warning is basically letting you know that you need to use a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) instead of a path if you want to pass parameters.

So instead of `this.$router.push({path:'/', params: { param: someValue } })` and:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  }
```

You would do something like `this.$router.push({name:'Home', params: { param: someValue } })` and:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  }
```

Some more info:

- [how to use vue-router params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296505/how-to-use-vue-router-params)
- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html